# Motorola Defy+: Black Screen and no BootLoader. How to discover what firmware version my device supports?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, motorola-defy

I did a terrible mistake. After some tentatives of installing cyanogen, I replaced the kernel with wrong version.

I have a Motorola Defy+ (MB526) and I'm trying to use RSD Lite to reflash the firmware.

I'm trying with the Retail Version from here http://sbf.droid-developers.org/umts_jordanplus/list.php.

The cellphone does nothing, only black screen. When I insert the usb cable and open RSD Lite, they recognizes and all the process to send the flash is done, the cell phone is booted automatically but I can't turn it on. When flashing, the cellphone screen show the message that the SW is being updated. The process seems to be done right, but at the end I can't start the operational system.

After finishing the process successfully, I can't turn it on. It's like nothing got flashed. Even the recovery mode was erased.

I don't know if I need some kind of boot loader (like some linux does) or other sbf file. Anyone knows if do I need to flash more files?

**Edited**

According here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1216982 It seems I downgraded the version, that's why I'm getting a black screen.

How do I know what is the version I need to use?
Can I try Chinese version? It seems that is the newer, but I'm afraid if I would face no English language option to set after installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months trying, I solved flashing the DEFYPLUS_U3_4.5.1-134_DFP-2311_BLUR_SIGN_USADEFYEMARAB1B8TFDE004.0R_PDS03C_USAJRDNGIBRO2DE_P020_A025_M002_Service1FF.sbf